# Keeping a count in a dictionary, bad result when running the code, good result adding inspections

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

Weird problem. Stepping through the code with inspections gives me correct answers. Just running it doesn't.

This program loops through each cell in a column, searching for a regex match. When it finds something, checks in a adjacent column to which group it belongs and keeps a count in a dictonary. Ex: Group3:7, Group5: 2, Group3:8

Just stepping through the code gives me incorrect results at the end, but adding and inspection for each known item in the dictionary does the trick. Using Debug.Print for each Dictionary(key) to check how many items I got in each loop also gives me a good output.

Correct // What really hapens after running the code

- Group1:23 //                           Group1:23
- Group3:21   //                         Group3:22
- Group6:2      //                       Group6:2
- Group7:3        //                     Group7:6
- Group9:8          //                   Group9:8
- Group11:1           //                 Group11:12
- Group12:2             //               Group12:21

  ```
  Sub Proce()

  Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
  Dim matches
  Dim Rango, RangoJulio, RangoAgosto As String
  Dim DictContador As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim conteo As Integer
  Dim Especialidad As String

  regEx.Pattern = "cop|col"
  regEx.Global = False 'True matches all occurances, False matches the first occurance
  regEx.IgnoreCase = True

  i = 3
  conteo = 1
  RangoJulio = "L3:L283"
  RangoAgosto = "L3:L315"
  Julio = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Julio")
  Rango = RangoJulio

  Julio.Activate
  For Each celda In Julio.Range(Rango)

      If regEx.Test(celda.Value) Then
          Set matches = regEx.Execute(celda.Value)
          For Each Match In matches  

              j = 13 'column M
              Especialidad = Julio.Cells(i, j).Value
              If (Not DictContador.Exists(Especialidad)) Then
                  Call DictContador.Add(Especialidad, conteo)
                  GoTo ContinueLoop
              End If
              conteo = DictContador(Especialidad)
              conteo = CInt(conteo) + 1
              DictContador(Especialidad) = conteo

          Next
      End If

  ContinueLoop:
  i = i + 1
  'Debug.Print DictContador(key1)
  'Debug.Print DictContador(key2)
  'etc

  Next

  'Finally, write the results in another sheet.

  End Sub
  ```

It's like VBA saying "I'm going to dupe you if I got a chance"

Thanks

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with you basically combining a `For i = 1...` loop in a `For Each` loop, which then happens by a [goto](http://xkcd.com/292/) statement.

Comment: Why use both Test and Matches?  Since you have Global set to false, there should only be one match, so I'm not sure what's the purpose of the inner loop?  Also, your code will be cleaner if you rove the GoTo and put the other statements in an Else block.

Comment: Does this code even compile?  You seem to be missing `Set` here `Julio = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Julio")`

Comment: @enderland you have a very good point there, I don't know how such a thing can mess so much the output but it seems to be a possible reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your main loop can be reduced to this:

```
For Each celda In Julio.Range(Rango)

    If regEx.Test(celda.Value) Then

        Especialidad = celda.EntireRow.Cells(13).Value

        'make sure the key exists: set initial count=0
        If (Not DictContador.Exists(Especialidad)) Then _
                          DictContador.Add Especialidad, 0

        'increment the count
        DictContador(Especialidad) = DictContador(Especialidad) +1

    End If

Next
```

Comment: This is excellent, I modified the code to be like yours and everithing just fixed itself, now I'm getting just correct answers, also, its narrower. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting different results stepping through the code because there's a bug/feature with dictionaries that if you inspect items using the watch or immediate window the items will be created if they don't already exist.

To see this put a break point at the first line under the variable declarations, press F5 to run to the break point, then in the immediate window type `set DictContador = new Dictionary` so the dictionary is initialised empty and add a watch for `DictContador("a")`. You will see `"a"` added as an item in the locals window.

Collections offer an alternative method that don't have this issue, they also show values rather than keys which may be more useful for debugging. On the other hand an `Exists` method is lacking so you would either need to add `on error resume next` and test for errors instead or add a custom collection class with an exists method added. There are trade-offs with both approaches.

Comment: Incredible, couldn't imagine that such a behavior would exist. The Tim Williams answer fixed the issue, yours expands my knowledge, thanks. I'll try to use collections next time and see what happens.